# Como validar um request RestAssured através de vários Metodos no Java?

Tags: java, cucumber

Eu estou desenvolvendo a Automação de testes de uma *API* usando *Rest Assured* e *Cucumber*, meu *feature* do *cucumber* está assim:

```
@criarConta
        Esquema do Cenario: Criar uma conta valida
            Dado que realizo a chamada no <ambiente> da <api> informando <token_admin> e um email e <senha> novos
            Entao devera retornar <status code>
```

Ou seja, eu faço a requisição em um step a validação em outro. Minha classe 'dataMap' (onde estão os metodos está assim):

```
public class dataMap extends tests {

    private Response response;
    private ValidatableResponse json;
    private RequestSpecification request;

        public void criarConta(String srtAmbiente, String srtAPI, String srtToken, String srtSenha) {

            String uriBase = srtAmbiente;
            String Api = srtAPI;

            int length = 15;
            String email = generateRandomEmail(length);
            System.out.println(email);
            Map<String, String> emailContent = new HashMap<String,String>();
            emailContent.put("email", email);
            Map<String, Object> postContent = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            postContent.put("customer", emailContent);
            postContent.put("password", srtSenha);

            request = RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+srtToken).with().body(postContent);

            response = request.when().post(uriBase+Api).prettyPeek();

        }

        public void responseCriarContaStatus (String srtStatusCode) {
            json = response.then().statusLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Se eu colocar a linha `json = response.then().statusLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` no método de cima "`criarConta`" ele executa certinho, porém como eu estou separando a validação ele não executa este segundo método. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigada

Comment: Oi Cleicy. Posso não estar familiarizado com alguma particularidade do seu projeto, mas não deveria ter um `@Test` nestes métodos de teste? Como o framework sabe quais métodos são de testes e quais não são? Em um teste Junit normal, os métodos com `@Test` são todos chamados na classe.

Comment: Olá! Eu tenho uma outra classe "steps" com tem @Test pro Junit e os steps do Cucumber, e cada step chama um método.